# Python - Selenium - implicit wait for multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-3.x

Currently I use implicit wait to locate elements before issuing any action upon them.  See example of implicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH(('xpath')))
```

This works fine when dealing with a single element.  However, it appears that if the xpath relates to multiple elements then `EC.presence_of_element_located()` will time out.  My question is, how do I do an implicit wait for multiple elements?

### Clarification:

Single element -

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH(('xpath')))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

Multiple element -

```
??
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
```

Note:  Notice use of `find_elements_by_xpath()` in multiple element instance instead of using `find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: In the examples, it should be `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'xpath'))`, not ByXPATH(('xpath))

Comment: Please correct me someone if I am wrong, but the above implementation is ExplicitWait and not ImplicitWait right?
Because according to [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) we call implicit wait as `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that it is simpler for a single item. It just has to wait until your locator returns a single, or more, elements.

When you deal with *multiple* elements, WebDriver cannot possibly know how long to wait because it has no idea about *how many* elements you expect to be there.

So you'll have to use an explicit wait instead.

In this explicit wait, you should:

1. Run `find_elements_by_path`
2. Check the result from the step is a collection that contains the amount of elements you need. If this isn't equal to the number you expect, you can let the "waiter" fail fast and go round again.
3. If the above is true, you can exit your "waiting", otherwise, let the "waiter" go round again.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 21):

I'm over two years late but I want to post this in case someone googles their way here like I did. You can use

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'xpath'))
)
```

and that will return all of them. You don't need to do

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

after your explicit wait because `WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(...)` will return the element(s) you are waiting for.

Comment: Can you describe what language you used, cz in my python `wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='someTable']/tbody/tr/td[7]")))` make my container request another container to run(i mean **error**).